# Pass a model and a separate list to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I have a partial view with a model for the user to complete required fields.  Along with those fields I have a jQuery multiselect dropdown where multiple entries can be selected.  How do I pass the model and the list to the controller?

If you need more info let me know.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("AddNewMeeting", "Meeting")',
        data: $("#formAddAppointment").serializeArray(),
        success: function (data) {

    var rooms=[];
    var $ddl = $("#ddlRoomsMulti");
    $ddl.find('option:selected').each(function(){
        rooms.push({value:$(this).val(),text:$(this).text()});
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your controller action result has two parameters like so:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyPageModel model, List<string> selectedValues)
{
    //SOME CODE...
}
```

I would make the 'data' property in your $.ajax request something like:

```js
data: {
    model : $('form').serialize(),
    selectedValues: $('select option:selected').map(function(i, obj){ return $(obj).val(); });
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you console.log (is your JS or using dev tools) and inspect this: $('form').serialize(), does it match your model definition?

Comment: Yes, it matches, but still comes in as null

Comment: Try adding `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax call. That will tell the server what to expect.

Comment: Using that the process never makes it to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

he time being until a better way comes up, I simply added the name and ID of each selected room to a string, which is part of the model in a hidden variable of the view.  I then simply split the string and add meetings for each member.